# addSubView:mapView not showing initial view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xcode4.5

I have two view controllers. In the first view controller(appViewController), I have a button, on pressing which it should push to the next view controller, which has a map view. I have set the first view controller as Initial View Controller. The problem is that when the build runs, it directly goes to the second view, instead of the first. The problem lies somewhere here:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    MapView* mapViewer = [[MapView alloc] initWithFrame:
                         CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];

    [self.view addSubview:mapViewer];

    Place* home = [[Place alloc] init];
    home.name = @"Home";
    home.description = @"Sweet home";
    home.latitude = 22.72299;
    home.longitude = 75.857506;

    Place* office = [[Place alloc] init];
    office.name = @"Office";
    office.description = @"Bad office";
    office.latitude = 23.272258;
    office.longitude = 77.413788;


    [mapViewer showRouteFrom:home to:office];

}
```

If I remove this line :[self.view addSubview:mapViewer];, then I only get a simple map and not one that I want (The map I want is one that shows route between two locations. That functionality is working fine). But the first scene is then visible. How to fix this, so that I get all the preceding screens to the mapView screen, and the proper map is loaded?
I'm using Xcode 4.5 and storyboard.

Comment: this one which view controller?

Comment: FirstViewController has one button. When u press button it will push to SecondeViewController that has MapView. Is it right ?

Comment: @sovannath yes.. Actually I changed self.view to self.mapView and the problem was resolved.